# Limit an ordered list in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this:

```
name  |  age
______|_____
Anne  |  28
Carl  |  20 
Sarah |  13
Lucy  |  56
John  |  22 
Mark  |  44
```

How do I retrieve the name of the 3 youngest people with Firebase?

I tried with:

`return firebase.database().ref('myUsers').orderByChild("age").startAt().limit(3);`

but I get an error:

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

Comment: `limit()` was a method in version 1.x of our API. In version 2 (and 3) it was replaced by `limitToFirst()` and `limitToLast()`. Since you're using version 3.x of the SDK, you need to use the corresponding `limitToLast()` call (as Matthew already answered, I see).

Comment: Also, you've received the error because [`startAt`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#startAt) needs to be passed a value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Data in firebase is ordered lexicographically, so you'll have to get the last of them.

```
return firebase.database().ref('myUsers').orderByChild("age").limitToLast(3);
```

Docs with example: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#limitToLast